# How to make chainable methods (scopes) with conditions not tied to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, scopes

I have a model `Item`, which has a relation to itself.

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subitems, :class_name => "Item", :foreign_key => "superitem_id"
  belongs_to :superitem, :class_name => "Item"
end
```

And I want to query all items which have a parent. Firstly I've tried to check if parent_id is present `Item.where("superitem_id != ?", false)`, or something like this. But it doesn't work. Although that item has superitem_id, superitem can be already destroyed. So I have to do it with class method

```
def self.with_superitems
  items = []
  self.find_each do |i|
    items << i if i.superitem
  end
  return items
end
```

But it makes chaining impossible, and I want to chain it with similar methods, like

```
def self.can_be_stored
  items = []
  self.find_each do |i|
    items << i if i.can_be_stored?
  end
  return items
end
```

Is it possible to achieve the same results with scopes?
Or what would you do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar issue in the past. It's sometimes difficult to get round it. I found a hack-ish way of doing it for my purposes so hope this will help...

```
 ids = []
 self.find_each do |i|
    ids << i.id if i.superitem
 end
Model.where('id in (?)', ids)
```

Comment: Thank's! Seems like it works =)
By the way, i don't  understand it good enough yet, but your `items.inject([]){|a,b| a+=[b.id]}` can be replaced by `items.map(&:id)`

Comment: Thanks, I've tidied it up a bit anyway so it doesn't need to loop through the list twice

Comment: Nope. It doesn't chain. `Item.countable.occupied # []`, `Item.countable.occupied.to_sql # "SELECT \"items\".* FROM \"items\" WHERE (id in (10,40)) AND (id in (NULL)) ORDER BY name asc"`. And it hoped it would be like `(Item.countable & Item.occupied) # [#<Item id: 40, name: "abs">]`, `(Item.countable & Item.occupied).to_sql # "SELECT \"items\".* FROM \"items\" WHERE (id in (10,40)) AND (id in (18,40,45)) ORDER BY name asc"`

Answer (score 1):

In rails 2 i would have done this

```
items = Item.find(:all, :include => [:superitems], :conditions => ["superitems.id is not null"])
```

the rails3 equivalent of this is

```
Item.includes([:superitem]).where("superitems.id is not null").all
```

This way you're pulling in the parent and testing if the id field on the superitem side of the join has an id.  if it doesn't, it's because there's no superitem there (or, technically, it could be there but have no id.  But this would normally never happen).

Comment: It doesn't work. I think it's because there's no `superitem` table (item relates to itself as superitem). `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: superitems.id`

Comment: Well. I think there are actually three questions in my post. 1) Is it possible to make chainable class methods. 2) How to pull only instances with parents using sql query. And 3) how to do it in case of self relation. You definitely answered the second one. So thank you =)

Comment: ah yes, forgot that it was self referential, sorry.  I think :dependent => :nullify is the way to go anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The following will get all the items with a parent, I'm not sure what you mean when you say "Although that item has superitem_id, superitem can be already destroyed"

```
items = Item.where("superitem_id IS NOT NULL")
```

Comment: I mean, that when I'm destroying superitem. Item still has superitem_id.
    @item.superitem_id # outputs 31
    Item.find(31).destroy
    @item.superitem_id # still outputs 31

It means, that there is no superitem, so your `Item.where("superitem_id IS NOT NULL")` doesn't get all the items with a parent, but just all the items with a superitem_id

Comment: @ilzoff Before deleting an item why not loop through all of its children and remove the superitem_id? that way you don't have any redundant data and you can keep things clean and simple?

Comment: Yeah. I definitely will do this. Especially now, because I've found `:dependent => :nullify` =)